# Express.js Routing is not making sense

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on an Express.js app and I think I am having trouble understanding the nuances of multi-layer routing. My app has the following segment of code in its **app.js** file:

```
//app.js

var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

//new stuff

const routes = require('./routes');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// middleware functions required
app.use(logger('dev'));  //handles logging
app.use(express.json()); //JSON payload parser
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //urlencoded payload parser
app.use(cookieParser());

//content routes
app.use('/jquery', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist/'));
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); //static files (css and other js files)
app.use('/', routes); //everything else (see /routes/index.js)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});
.
.
.
```

As indicated in the code, after a bunch of static file and default middleware setup for logging and such, **app.use('/', routes);** is declared, handing off to an index.js file in the /routes folder as follows:

```
//index.js
//main router entry point, sets up all route modules

//instantiate the express.Router class
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//import our route modules
const indexRouter = require('./indexRouter');
const resetRouter = require('./resetRouter');
const enrollRouter = require('./enrollRouter');

//map individual route modules to their respective routes
router.use('/', indexRouter);
router.use('/reset', resetRouter);
router.use('/enroll(/*)?', enrollRouter);

module.exports = router;
```

The three router.use lines call individual route files in the same directory as shown. The first two are simple get routes. The third one (**router.use('/enroll(/*)?', enrollRouter);**) has both get and post components via the enrollRouter.js file as follows:

```
//enrollRouter.js

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const { getEnroller }  = require('../controllers/enrollGetController');
const { postEnrollment } = require('../controllers/enrollPostController');

router.post(/^(\/enroll\/new)/i, postEnrollment);
//router.post('/', postEnrollment);
router.get('/', getEnroller);

module.exports = router;
```

Here's where things get interesting. I'm using postman to make a post request to "/route/new". If the route string for the **post** route in the code above is set to '/', everything works fine, and **enrollPostController.js** is called returning appropriate content. However, if I set the route string to **'/enroll/new'** instead (the path I'm calling... doesn't matter if it's a string or a regex), the 404 error code in app.js is called.

I'm not following what is going on. I'm under the impression that the string at the beginning of a router.get or router.post call represents the path to be matched for the callback defined as the next parameter. When the path is clearly the one specified, why am I getting a 404?

The way I'm thinking, when the /enroll/new post request comes in, app.js should hand off to index.js for all routes matching '/'. Then index.js should hand off to enrollRouter because the route matches '/enroll(/*)?'. And then finally, enrollRouter.js should call postEnrollment defined over in ../controllers/enrollPostController, because the route matches '/enroll/new'. But it doesn't work that way.

Can someone enlighten? or fill in the holes in my understanding?

Here's the code in enrollPostController.js

```
//enrollPostController.js

module.exports = {
  postEnrollment(erq, res) {
    //at this point we have the form submission data.
    console.log(erq.body);
    res.send("received form submission!");
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

**routes/index.js**

```
// Delegate "/enroll/*" to router
router.use('/enroll', enrollRouter);
```

**routes/enrollRouter.js**

```
// Handle POST requests to "/enroll/new"
router.post('/new', postEnrollment);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This did the trick and it makes the most sense by way of explanation, at least to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following some pattern and only endpoints are getting changed for example

```
http://localhost:4000/mycode/testUrl/abc
http://localhost:4000/mycode/testUrl/Pqr/xyz
http://localhost:4000/mycode/testUrl/abc/xyz/pqs
const service = express.Router();
// **console** is just to check your endUrl. you can print originalUrl as well
service.get('/*', function(req, res) {console.log(req.url); }
service.post('/*', function(req, res) { console.log(req.url);} 

app.use('/mycode/testUrl', service);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **index.js**

The express router defined as

```
router.use('/enroll(/*)?', enrollRouter);
```

passes the '/enroll/new' to your **enrollRouter.js**

so all you need to give the "/" in the post route, so the "/enroll/new" is right in front of it but due to nesting of routes we can separate them.

Hope I answered the question.